# Banner images look different when the WordPress theme is on the server?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I created my own WordPress theme. It was looking great and I tweaked everything on my local version. After I moved the theme on the web server and there are many problems. But I am msot concerned about the headers.

Above my header.php code and the corresponding css styling:

```
 //If page is with id 27- load css class called bannerHome

if(is_page(27))
{$class_name='bannerHome';}


 //the img/ forlder is  located in the theme folder. 

div.bannerHome{
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
background-image:  url(img/bigbg.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position:fixed; 
background-color: black;
}
```

As a result the banner does nor cover the whole page.At the end of the page there is big white spot.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] showing your error.  We cannot help you if all you show is that one class

Comment: The question is not clear. The image is not loaded on the production version but it does on localhost ? Or it looks different ?